# Has ruby 2.5 been tested with Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, version

We are looking to upgrade ruby from 2.2, but not yet Rails.

It seems that ruby 2.4 has been tested with rails 4.2, but not 2.5.

Can anyone confirm or contradict this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version of Rails which brings official (and tested) Ruby 2.5 support is Rails 5.1. With earlier versions of Rails, you might still be able to get it running, but will probably stumble upon roadblocks sooner or later.

Thus, if you need Ruby 2.5 support, you should use at least Rails 5.1. If you need to use earlier versions of Rails, use it with Ruby 2.4. Rails supports Ruby 2.4 since version 4.2.8.